# xml query with sql

Tags: sql, xml

I have an XML column:

```
<xmlList> 
   <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>ACHER</sug>
   </XMLEntity>

  <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>DOA</sug>
   </XMLEntity>
</xmlList>
```

In this way I get just the `sug` node:

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug' passing 
KTOVET ) as char large object) as XXX 
FROM "TABLE"
```

How can I get the `sug` nodes where its value is "ACHER"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this XQuery expression :

```
//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.="ACHER"]
```

Comment: I get lines that their `sug` but their value is `DOA` as empty lines, since they indeed have `sug`. How can I filter them so they will not appear? Thanks in advance1